# Array and pointer notation in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Since `array[i]` is the same as `*(array+i)`, does this mean that
`array[i+1]` is the same as `*(array+i+1)`? If not, what is the correct pointer notation for `array[i+1]`?

Comment: Yes it does mean that.

Comment: "Correct" would be to not use pointer notation for an array.

Comment: Even better: `const char a[] = "Hello World"; const char *p = &a[4]; char c = -1[p];`

Comment: `array[i] === *(array + i) === *(i + array) === i[array]`

Comment: `array[i+1] === *(array + i + 1) === *(1 + array + i) === 1[array + i] === 1[&i[array]]`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow That `char c = -1[p];` in your first comment should really be  `char c = (-1)[p];` — note the parentheses, because the unary minus operator has lower [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than subscript operator.

Comment: yeah, it's even better with parentheses.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow perverts

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite this record

```
array[i] = *(array+i)
```

like

```
array[i] = *( (array ) + ( i ) )
```

Instead of the identifier `i` you can use any expression that produces an integer value.

Pay only attention to that the expression denoted by the name array shall be a postfix expression. So for example these records

`array[i++]` and `i++[array]` are equivalent while these records `array[++i]` and `++i[array]` are different.